# SQL query to calculate total per month as a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I am stuck on a SQL query. I am using PostgreSQL. I need to get the total for each month for all states.

```
table A 
--------------------------------------------------------
created    |    Name    | Agent_id  | Total
--------------------------------------------------------
3/14/2013  |    Harun   | 1A        |  5                
3/14/2013  |    Hardi   | 2A        | 20
4/14/2013  |    Nizar   | 3A        | 30
5/14/2013  |    moyes   | 4A        | 20

table B 
----------------------------
Agent_id| state_id
----------------------------
1A      | 1
2A      | 1 
3A      | 1
4A      | 2

table C 
----------------------------
state_id   |    State   
----------------------------
   1       |    Jakarta 
   2       |    Singapore
   3       |    Kuala lumpur
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No  |State          | Januari | February | March | April | Mei  ... December| Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |Jakarta        |0        |0         |25     |  30   |  0   ...         | 55
2   |Singapore      |0        |0         | 0     |   0   | 20   ...         | 20
3   |Kuala Lumpur   |0        |0         | 0     |   0   |  0   ...         |  0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to have all state with no data in table A / B you have to use `OUTER JOIN`

to complete @bma answer

```
  select  
  no,
  state,
  sum(case when month = 1 then total else 0 end) as januari,
  sum(case when month = 2 then total else 0 end) as februari,
  sum(case when month = 3 then total else 0 end) as mars,
  sum(case when month = 4 then total else 0 end) as april,
  sum(case when month = 5 then total else 0 end) as may,
  sum(case when month = 6 then total else 0 end) as juni,
  sum(case when month = 7 then total else 0 end) as juli,
  sum(case when month = 8 then total else 0 end) as august,
  sum(case when month = 9 then total else 0 end) as september,
  sum(case when month = 10 then total else 0 end) as october,
  sum(case when month = 11 then total else 0 end) as november,
  sum(case when month = 12 then total else 0 end) as december,
  sum(coalesce(total,0)) as total
from (
    select  
      c.state_id as no,
      extract(month from created) as month,
      state,
      sum(total) as total
    from tablec c 
      left join tableb b on ( b.state_id = c.state_id)
      left join tablea a on ( a.agent_id = b.agent_id)
    group by c.state_id,state,month
    ) sales
    group by no,state;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d1e01/1)

Comment: Hi Kobi, can you please pay more attention when reviewing in Suggested Edits? While I haven't found anything blatantly incorrect in your review history, you definitely seem to be approving everything you see without regard for quality, including things you don't appear to have any expertise in and things that I personally would have rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i do not know much about postgres sql this is a try see if this works

try this

```
Select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP table A.created) , 
table C.State , SUM(Total) From table A , table B , table C 
Where table A.Agent_id = table B.Agent_id
And  table B.state_id = table C.state_id
Group by table C.State , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP table A.created);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should give you results like your sample results. I'm not sure what the "No" column was though. This query is untested.

```
select  state,
        sum(case when mm = 1 then total else 0 end) as jan,
        sum(case when mm = 2 then total else 0 end) as feb,
        sum(case when mm = 3 then total else 0 end) as mar,
        sum(case when mm = 4 then total else 0 end) as apr,
        sum(case when mm = 5 then total else 0 end) as may,
        sum(case when mm = 6 then total else 0 end) as jun,
        sum(case when mm = 7 then total else 0 end) as jul,
        sum(case when mm = 8 then total else 0 end) as aug,
        sum(case when mm = 9 then total else 0 end) as sep,
        sum(case when mm = 10 then total else 0 end) as oct,
        sum(case when mm = 11 then total else 0 end) as nov,
        sum(case when mm = 12 then total else 0 end) as dec,
        sum(total) as total
from (
    select  extract(month from created) as mm,
            state,
            sum(total) as total
    from table_a
    group by state,mm
    ) s
group by state;
```